# change TimeZone display type from new java.util.Date() in android

Tags: android, timezone, format

When I print the new java.util.Date() it prints this in Android

Thu Feb 22 05:30:00 Asia/Calcutta 2007

I need this to be print as Thu Feb 22 05:30:00 IST 2007

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys I got my problem solved. Here is the solution what I adapted

I had the date in format in dd-mm-yy which I need to convert like Thu Feb 22 05:30:00 IST 2007

so I just created the object of the `SimpleDateFormat` class with the desire format suiting the format Thu Feb 22 05:30:00 IST 2007 and finally called `format()` method on `SimpleDateFormat` instance